# ACF: Dynamically populate select field with repeater relationship subfield

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Used the awesome solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35502576/how-to-get-advanced-custom-field-choice-value-from-another-advance-custom-field/35503328) to populate multiple select fields with text fields inside a repeater field. The issue is I need to use a user (relational) field instead and this field is returning anything in the select box. This is the code I'm using, wondering if I need to call a relational field in a different way..?

FYI:

- Repeater field is `co_designated_employee_representative`
- User field is `co_der`
- Select field to be populated is `test_selection`

Here is my snippet:

```
function acf_load_marke_name_field_choices($field)
 {
global $post;
//Get the repeater field values
$choices = get_field('co_designated_employee_representative',$post->ID);
// loop through array and add to field 'choices'
if (is_array($choices)) {
    foreach ($choices as $choice) {
        //Set the select values
        $field['choices'][$choice['co_der']] = $choice['co_der'];
    }
}

// return the field
return $field;
} 

add_filter('acf/load_field/name=test_selection', 'acf_load_marke_name_field_choices');
```

EDIT**

Found that if I added the select field name to the first $choice I ended up with an array of usermeta.

```
function select_my_field($field)
 {
global $post;
//Get the repeater field values
$choices = get_field('co_designated_employee_representative',$post->ID);
// loop through array and add to field 'choices'
if (is_array($choices)) {
foreach ($choices as $choice) {
    //Set the select values
    $field['choices'][$choice['test_selection']] = $choice['co_der'];
    }
}

// return the field
return $field;
} 

add_filter('acf/load_field/name=test_selection', 'select_my_field');
```

This change gave me all the chosen usermeta in the select dropdown, but I (a) only need first and last name and (b) if more than one user was chosen the select field would only show usermeta for the last user in the repeater field.

[Screenshot of populated select field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXz5B.jpg)

Comment: Can you give some more info? Is this your actual code or just a copy paste of the answer you linked to? What is the name of user field and what is the name of the field you are trying to connect it to?

Comment: Question edited to add further details

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function select_my_field( $field ) {

    global $post;

    //Get the repeater field values
    $employees = get_field( 'co_designated_employee_representative', $post->ID );
    $choices = array();


    if ( is_array( $employees ) ) {

        // loop through the employees selected in the repeater
        foreach ( $employees as $employee ) {

            $id = $employee['co_der']['ID'];
            $name = $employee['co_der']['user_firstname'] . ' ' . $employee['co_der']['user_lastname'];

            // the user ID becomes the key and the user name is the value
            $choices[$id] = $name;
        }
    }

    // if we have new choices set the choices for our select field
    if ( $choices ) {
        $field['choices'] = $choices;
    }

    // return the field
    return $field;
}

add_filter( 'acf/load_field/name=test_selection', 'select_my_field' );
```

I'm assuming the following

- You have a repeater with the name: **co_designated_employee_representative**
- Within that repeater is a field named: **co_der** that let's you select a user
- You have a field named: **test_selection** that should pull from the users selected in the repeater

When you go to retrieve `test_selection` in your templates it will return the user ID.